# Check if the logged in user is active or not

Tags: apex, user

I have a transaction that will occur only if a user is Active. Following is the way I tried

```
 User u = [select id,isActive from user where id=:userinfo.getuserid()];
     if(!u.isActive())
     {
          flag = false;

         ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.Error,'Error. User not Active.'));

     }
```

Following is the error I get..

> Error: Compile Error: Method does not exist or incorrect signature: User.IsActive()

Comment: please clearly tell us what is problem you are facing?

Comment: I'm confused what's the real requirement here. If the user is inactive how he/she can log in?

Comment: m sorry i will update the question

Comment: This doesn't make sense, the current user will always be active.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your code above isActive used as a method, but it's a filed in User object, try `if ( !u.isActive) {`

Comment: More to the point, the user *is* active, by definition, because they would not be allowed to execute the code if they were not.

Comment: Thanks to both of you. Now I get this error    Error: Compile Error: Method does not exist or incorrect signature: UserInfo() ..

Comment: UserInfo is a standard class, not a method.

Comment: @sfdcfox They would. For example, you have scheduled some class that starts batch in it, then deactivated user who submitted scheduled job. The job still runs and batch fails with `[INACTIVE_OWNER_OR_USER]`. You should check if the user is active in scheduled job and abort it in case that it isn't.

Comment: @MariiaIllarionova As far as I'm aware, the scheduled job would fail to run, because the user is inactive. Aside from that, there's no need to abort early in most cases, because it would simply fail to run and the admins would see this in the logs. If you didn't abort it, the admin would have no idea that a job failed to run.

Comment: @sfdcfox Nope, have just confirmed that scheduled job won't fail, only batch job that is run from it. At least in scheduled job from managed package.

Comment: @MariiaIllarionova Interesting. I think I'd still rather see that error in the logs than have it just disappear because we aborted early based on the check, but that really depends on the business logic required. At least I learned something out of it. Thanks!